# how to check the size of the folder on terminal using fast method

Tags: ios, unix, hpc

I know following command gives the size of a particular folder. But it takes longer time when I am using this command on HPC. Is there any other fast command to get the size of folder.

```
du -sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only slow because it's recursive.  The deeper and larger the subfolder structure, the longer it will take to traverse.

You tagged both iOS and high performance computing -- I am assuming iOS was a mistake.  Depending on your filesystem you may have other options.

For example, on OS X you can use the index created by spotlight in a command-line fashion:

```
Usage: mdfind [-live] [-count] [-onlyin directory] [-name fileName | -s smartFolderName | query]
list the files matching the query
query can be an expression or a sequence of words

    -attr <attr>      Fetches the value of the specified attribute
    -count            Query only reports matching items count
    -onlyin <dir>     Search only within given directory
    -live             Query should stay active
    -name <name>      Search on file name only
    -reprint          Reprint results on live update
    -s <name>         Show contents of smart folder <name>
    -0                Use NUL (``\0'') as a path separator, for use with xargs -0.

example:  mdfind image
example:  mdfind -onlyin ~ image
example:  mdfind -name stdlib.h
example:  mdfind "kMDItemAuthor == '*MyFavoriteAuthor*'"
example:  mdfind -live MyFavoriteAuthor
```

The details on the [MDItem used by mdfind is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html).

For the most part though, this is something you could calculate yourself, then check periodically.  Store the result in a cache like [memcached](http://memcached.org) or [ehcache](http://ehcache.org).  Depending on which journaled file system you use, you could get notifications when a folder is changed and recalculate that folder only.